# No signature files found in META-INF. Cannot proceed (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, calabash, calabash-android

I am trying to use calabash-android to start a test sever on a phone in android studio. I am new to this and gotten this far thanks to tutorials.

I downloaded java, ruby, calabash-android, set-up environment variables, created a key store in the `.calabash-settings`, have a `.debug-keystore` file in my `.android` folder.

I am stuck as to what this problem is I can run `bundle exec calabash-android resign app-debug.apk` fine but when i do `bundle exec calabash-android run app-debug.apk`, I get the following error message. I am obviously missing something but i am unsure what:

```
C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\Calabash>bundle exec calabash-android build app-debug.apk
WARNING: skipped META-INF/CERT.RSA as unsafe
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
        7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
        6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/bin/calabash-android:76:in `<top (required)>'
        5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:2:in `calabash_build'
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:162:in `fingerprint_from_apk'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
        2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:163:in `block in fingerprint_from_apk'
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:163:in `chdir'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:177:in `block (2 levels) in fingerprint_from_apk': **No signature files found in META-INF. Cannot proceed. (RuntimeError)**
```

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There is no code involved. I'm just trying to set up a test server to run calabash on my android device.

Comment: Why do you need bundle exec, Could you run using calabash-android run apk-debug.apk

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with latest available versions of ruby (v3.0.2p107) and calabash (v0.9.22).

I avoided the issue by using "bundle install" command and specifying a GemFile with previous versions.

```
    # Contents of Gemfile
    source "https://rubygems.org"
    
    ruby "2.5.1"

    gem 'calabash-android', '0.9.5'
    gem 'cucumber'
    gem 'rexml'
    gem 'rubyzip', '1.2.1'
```

You may want to refer to similar issues raised such as https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/802